# jQuery animate height not toggle expand every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am having trouble getting jQuery animate to work .To start the div is hidden with .hide(), then onclick of a button I want to expand the height of the div. Toggle animate works perfect, but I don't want toggle.

Toggle does this:  The div is hidden, I fire the code below, works perfect, then the div gets hidden, fire it again- the div pops up full height and the animates down to 0px.  I want it to go from hidden to expanding every time.

```
$('#logincontainer').animate(
    { 'height':  'toggle' }, 'slow'
);
```

I tried

```
{ 'height':  '552px' }, 'slow'
{ 'height':  'auto' }, 'slow'

var h = document.getElementById('logincontainer').scrollHeight;
{ 'height':  h + 'px' }, 'slow'
```

I just want to expand the height to 552px, which the div already is every time.

Comment: You can't really animate between hidden and a height, as those are different things.  You could animate the height between 0 and 552, or use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`, or if it's at the top of the screen you could animate its `top` between 0 and -552

Comment: [sample fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8Zc2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#logincontainer').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ktx9E/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
         $('#logincontainer').animate(
             { 'height':  'show' }, 'slow'
          );
```

'show' was the magic jQuery word I was looking for to expand everytime, I will have to manually set the height back to 0 when hidden as well.